# Python cleaning data

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove unwanted characters from  a large text file (about 3GB). I'm trying to remove unwanted forward and backslashes throughout the file. I wanted to keep the Tilde between the words, it acts as a delimiter. The file is formatting like this:

```
Cornet~Chris Tyle
Cornet\~Warren Vache
Cornet~Roger Webster
Cornet~\Grimethorpe Coll//iery Band
Cornet/~Daniel Rollston
Cornet~Murley Silver Band
Chocolate~Chocolate liquor
Chocolate~Theobroma cacao
Chocolate~Meso/america
```

So In the example above I would want to remove all the back/forward slashes so the words are readable(while keeping tilde). Would I use a Python Regex expression for this? Another possibility is just removing the lines that contain a slash but I want to leave that as a last resort kind of thing.

**EDIT: Sorry forgot to mention one thing! Some of the lines appear like this:

```
Chocolate~
Chocolate~Theobroma cacao
         ~Mesoamerica
```

I have to also delete all the lines that are null either before or after the Tilde in addition to removing the forward and back slashes**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Python is overkill for this, it would take, like... five lines! `tr -d /\\ < dirty.txt > clean.txt`

Comment: i know what you mean. i wouldn't be using python if i didn't have to!

Comment: Updated for new requirements: `tr -d /\\ < dirty.txt | grep -v '^\s*~\|~\s*$' > clean.txt`. I don't get why you'd *have to* use Python unless it's homework; and homeworks usually don't involve 3Gb files...

Comment: @Amadan Does Windows have `tr` or are you just assuming that we're all on linux? :)

Comment: @jDo: [It does](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm), and I assume people are on *nix, not Linux (I'm on OSX mostly), as Windows is too painful to develop on :P

Comment: Cool, I had no idea. Been on Linux for a long time now and I agree. *nix is much easier and safer all in all. I have no plans of going back to the malware magnet :) I hear good things about Visual Studio, c# seems nice and lots of companies seem to love .NET but I'll be damned if I have to install it at home hehe

Answer (score 2):

Would something really simple like this do? (I believe `for line in f` is a generator. Either way, it only reads one line at a time)

```
with open(filename, "r") as f: 
     for line in f: 
         line = line.replace("/", "") 
         line = line.replace("\\", "")
```

**UPDATE** (OP also wants to *"delete all the lines that are null either before or after the Tilde "*)

This will skip lines where a tilde is preceded by white-space and replace forward and backward slashes in the rest:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\s+~')

with open(filename, "r") as f: 
    for line in f: 
        if not pattern.match(line):
            line = line.replace("/", "") 
            line = line.replace("\\", "")
            print line
```

NB: If what you really want is simply to keep all lines with the format "word + tilde + word", remove slashes and discard everything else, stating that would make it easier to understand.

Comment: I would want to elete entire line if either side of the Tilde has whitespace or null. Would the line.replace() method work for lines such as this too?

    O.P.P.\~O.P.P. song

Comment: What do you mean by "null"? You're not talking about null bytes, `\0`, as in  null-terminated c-strings, are you? But yes, `string.replace()` will remove any occurrence of the character or combination of characters you provide and replace it with the second argument - in this case an empty string. If you want to remove white space ONLY before or after a tilde, it gets slightly more complex

Answer (score 2):

Easy, just use `str.replace()`.

*Note the double `\\`, It's not replacing double backslashes but rather one backslash is escaping the other*

**Code:**

```
def clean():
    with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
        outputs = []
        for line in f:
            output = line.replace('/', '')
            output = output.replace('\\', '')
            output = output.replace('\n', '')
            outputs.append(output)
    return outputs

print(clean())
```

**Output:**

```
['Cornet~Chris Tyle', 'Cornet~Warren Vache', 'Cornet~Roger Webster', 'Cornet~Grimethorpe Colliery Band', 'Cornet~Daniel Rollston', 'Cornet~Murley Silver Band', 'Chocolate~Chocolate liquor', 'Chocolate~Theobroma cacao', 'Chocolate~Mesoamerica']
```

Comment: How would you do this without reading in the entire file, any other solutions (iterating over a file and writing out somehow)? Just curious.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry forgot to mention one thing! Some of the lines appear like this:

    Chocolate~
    Chocolate~Theobroma cacao
                      ~Mesoamerica

I have to also delete all the lines that are null either before or after the Tilde in addition to removing the forward and back slashes

Comment: `f.read().split()` is even worse, now you have a 3Gb string *and* an array in memory... If you absolutely have to do it in Python, the correct way is what @jDo does, reading a line at a time.

Comment: Are you sure you want to load 3GB into memory? try to use the way from jDo's answer. +1 for split, it can cripple his text if it's left out.

Comment: so if i wanted to replace double backslashes i would have to put triple backslashes?

Comment: @Signal Is removing newlines and creating a list what OP wants? I might have missed that. Anyway, lists are quite bad memory-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(ur'[/\\]+', re.MULTILINE)

inFile = "input.txt"
outFile = "output.txt"

with open(inFile, 'r') as f_in:
    with open(outFile,'w') as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            cleanLine = re.sub(rx, '', line).strip()
            if cleanLine.startswith('~') or cleanLine.endswith('~'):
                continue
            f_out.write(cleanLine + '\n')
```

This code is removing `\ /` and lines starting or ending with tilda `~` from input file and writing a cleaned output file.

Based on input text, it will emit

```
Cornet~Chris Tyle
Cornet~Warren Vache
Cornet~Roger Webster
Cornet~Grimethorpe Colliery Band
Cornet~Daniel Rollston
Cornet~Murley Silver Band
Chocolate~Chocolate liquor
Chocolate~Theobroma cacao
Chocolate~Mesoamerica
Chocolate~Theobroma cacao
```

Comment: I think this is good. I'm not exactly sure what OP is after but if he/she only wants lines that contain two tilde-separated words, stripping the lines and looking for a starting or ending tilde is the way to go -  better than looking for white-space like I was doing. +1